# template argument required for class

Tags: c++

I have a dynamic array-based class that I'm calling `MyList`, that looks as follows:

```
#ifndef MYLIST_H
#define MYLIST_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class type>
class MyList
{
public:
  MyList(); 
  ~MyList(); 
  int size() const;
  type at() const;
  void remove();
  void push_back(type);

private:
  type* List;
  int _size;
  int _capacity;
  const static int CAPACITY = 80;
};

#endif
```

I also have a another class that I'm calling `User` that I want to include an instance of `MyList` as a private data member. User looks like this:

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
#include "mylist.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class User
{
public:
  User();
  ~User();

private:
  int id;
  string name;
  int year;
  int zip;
  MyList <int> friends;
};

#endif
```

When I try to compile I get an error in my `user.cpp` file:

> undefined reference to `MyList::Mylist()`

I find this odd because `MyList` is completely unrelated to `user.cpp`, which only contains my User constructor and destructor.

Comment: Do you ever implement the constructor?

Comment: Class template's definitions must be available when instantiating them. You can't define your template in a source file as you usually do with non-template classes. Move the definition into the header file, or include the definition from the header file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you write both the declaration and the definition of your template class into the header (define *MyList* in the header not in a .cpp file)

Comment: what would be the format for the declaration of the template class in the header?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, so what should i add to the header then?

Comment: You add (move from the .cpp file) the definitions of _MyList_ constructor, destructor and all the member functions

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you did not provide `MyClass<int>` constructor definition. Unfortunatelly in C++ you cannot divide template class definition by declaring methods in header file and defining them in the implementation. At least if you want to use it in other modules. So in your case User class needs to have `MyClass<int>::MyClass()` definition right now. There are two ways to do it:

1. (the easiest one) provide constructor definition right in place:

   `MyClass() {
   ...
   }` or
2. add method definition in MyClass.h after class definition like that:

   `template<class type> MyList<type>::MyList() {
   ...
   }`